# How to use a foreign key variable without writing the specific foreign key column in the entity class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys

I have the following entity 'User' where the field 'companyId' is a foreign key:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
@Getter @Setter @ToString
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

@Column(name = "company_id")
private Long companyId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Company company;
```

The Company entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Companies")
@Getter @Setter @ToString
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
      
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<User> users;
```

I removed other irrelevant fields from the classes.
I'm using spring boot data jpa.
My question is how to remove the field 'companyId' and use the company id inside the field 'company' for CRUD functions with the DB.

Comment: Neither "companyId" nor "company" is a "variable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the companyId and make Company writable

```
@Entity

    @Table(name = "Users")
    @Getter @Setter @ToString
    public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;
```

Comment: When I try to add a user, the company_id column in the DB remains null. this is the JSON code i use 
{
  "company": {
    "id": 1
  }
}

Comment: How does Company look like? And how do you transform the JSON to the entities?

Comment: I accidentally put @JsonIgnore on 'company'. I removed it and it works. thanks!